# Can't save a file in a directory I created

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, path

I've created a folder using the following code:

```
def _infrastructure(self):
    lib = "data"
    try:
        os.makedirs(lib)
    except OSError as e:
        if e.errno != errno.EXIST:
            raise
```

And I want to save a file I'm creating using this code:

```
def save(self, dic):
    filename = "file.csv"           
    my_path = "data"
    filepath = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), my_path, filename)
    self.curr = csv.writer(open(filepath, "w"))            

    for key, val in self.dic.items():
        self.curr.writerow([key, val])
```

What I want to do is to save the file I've created in the folder that I've also created and it looks like the issue here is in the for loop, because all my variables do get the parameters.

The exception raised is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): self.curr = csv.writer(open(filepath, 
    "w")) FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 
    'C:\\Users\\user\\data\\file.csv'
```

Comment: Look at the line shown in the traceback.  It's the line that opens the file.  It's executed before it ever enters the for loop.  In other words, the for loop isn't even being reached before the exception occurs.

Comment: You may gain additional debugging information if you remove the `try..except` from around the call to `os.makedirs`. Perhaps there is some OSError where  `e.errno == errno.EXIST` that the `try..except` is silently swallowing.

Comment: `_infrastructure` expects that your working directory is `os.path.expanduser('~')` - is that really the case? You could put `print(os.getcwd())` in it and test again.